# Serial Communication on Windows

Tags: windows, serial-port, usb

Is it possible to communicate with a device with over a RS-232 interface when my computer has no serial port?

Scenario:
 I have a ethernet switch which has an RS-232 port.
 I must communicate with it using a windows 7 or a Windows 10 laptop.

I have found that some USB to serial converters do not have drivers which will work properly under windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the IOgear USB-232 Adapter model GUC232A works fine.

I am using a Dell E6410 w/ Windows 7 and a Lenovo Thinkpad P51s with Windows 10.

The GUC232A adapter only works with the Dell and Windows 7. The driver fails to install properly under Windows 10.

There is some mention of using Cygwin [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). I find that screen doesn't work.

[Putty](https://www.putty.org/) works well however.

So the best way that I have found to communicate with a device over RS232 from a Windows 7 Laptop over USB is to use an IOgear GUC232A  and Putty.